# Qt deployed executable opening blank application

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, qml, executable

I have created a project in Qt creator using C++ and QML on windows. I need to deploy my project as shared library, so I am using the windeployqt tool. Following are the steps followed:

1. Build the project in release mode without shadow build option selected.
2. Copied only the executable in a separate folder , path: D:\Deploy
3. In command prompt navigate to D:\Deploy and used the below command:
   D:\Deploy>windeployqt --qmldir 'path to project qml files' --release app.exe
4. This tool adds all the dependent files and required dll's as seen in the screenshot.

Deploy folder after executing above command:

[image]

5. When I double click on the app.exe in the D:\Deploy folder, it open up only a blank window.

Kindly suggest what is wrong in the process. The app executes fine in release configuration in Qt creator.

Comment: Try running from cmd, maybe I'll show you some message.

Comment: I tried. No messages on command prompt. It launches the application with blank screen. Is it possible that it might be related to incorrect graphics rendering settings?

Comment: The application launches perfectly fine when I copy the app.exe file from D:\Deploy and paste it in C:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin and execute.

Comment: Then you need to copy some dll

Comment: Try using: dependency walker http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Usually white screen means that QtQuick can't find its libraries.

Answer (score 0):

2 files were missing in the project path: D:\Deploy\QtQuick\Controls
1. qmldir
2. qtquickcontrolsplugin.dll

Added these manually and now the executable works fine. Thank you for your suggestions.
Can you suggest why these files were missing even after using windeployqt tool? Because it takes a lot of efforts and time to figure out the missing files.